# I have downloaded and installed magento site in localhost

Tags: magento2

I have downloaded and installed magento2 site in localhost, I am facing this issue
On home page of magento and in admin panel, everything works fine. PDP pages are working as will.

My app/etc/env.php is this

```
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'queue' => [
        'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => '18f0e350576e0fed94a950e30568cd6d'
    ],
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'dbname' => 'staginghbs',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'tiger',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [
                    1014 => false
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'files'
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'id_prefix' => 'd7e_'
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'id_prefix' => 'd7e_'
            ]
        ],
        'allow_parallel_generation' => false
    ],
    'lock' => [
        'provider' => 'db',
        'config' => [
            'prefix' => ''
        ]
    ],
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'vertex' => 1
    ],
    'downloadable_domains' => [
        'staging.hairbodyskin.com.au'
    ],
    'install' => [
        'date' => 'Mon, 31 May 2021 14:30:33 +0000'
    ]
];
```

If i brows category pages it throw this error
[image]

Enabling xdebug show this error.
How to fix this issue.
[image]

Comment: Can you disable amasty layered navigation and see if it works ? If it works, update the module.

Comment: Did you run setup:upgrade command and indexing?

Comment: As the code explicitly stated, I suppose you should try installing Redis service and have it integrated with your Magento 2 instance as well.